# What/which are Hadiths about optimism?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, reference-request, uloom-al-hadith

I already know Islam is optimistic religion but please kindly share few hadith with refrence

Hadith which motivate optimism

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some references for optimism:

- > I was in the company of the Prophet (ﷺ) in the cave, and on seeing the traces of the pagans, I said, "O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) If one of them (pagans) should lift up his foot, he will see us." He said, "What do you think of two, the third of whom is Allah?" ([Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/urn/179970))
- See also the lengthy Sahih hadith with the following statement also quoting the story of Hijrah:

  > …"Don't grieve for Allah is with us"... (For example in [Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/61/122))
- > "No fatigue, nor disease, nor sorrow, nor sadness, nor hurt, nor distress befalls a Muslim, even if it were the prick he receives from a thorn, but that Allah expiates some of his sins for that." ([Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/75/2))
- > Strange are the ways of a believer for there is good in every affair of his and this is not the case with anyone else except in the case of a believer for if he has an occasion to feel delight, he thanks (God), thus there is a good for him in it, and if he gets into trouble and shows resignation (and endures it patiently), there is a good for him in it. ([Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/55/82))

And in the hadith al-Qudsi:

- > “Allah, Blessed is He and Most High, said: ‘O son of Adam! Verily as long as you called upon Me and hoped in Me, I forgave you, despite whatever may have occurred from you, and I did not mind. O son of Adam! Were your sins to reach the clouds of the sky, then you sought forgiveness from Me, I would forgive you, and I would not mind. So son of Adam! If you came to me with sins nearly as great as the earth, and then you met Me not associating anything with Me, I would come to you with forgiveness nearly as great as it.’” ([Jami' at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/48/171))

And here some hadith references against pessimism:

- > When a person says that people are ruined he is himself ruined. Abu Ishaq said: I do not know whether he said" ahlakahum or ahlakuhum. ([Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/45/180))
- > There is no transitive disease, no divination, but good omen pleases me, i. e. the good word or a good word. ([Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/39/152))

We may further find many optimistic qur'an quotes, but this wasn't asked.